# When to remove unwanted buds

Tags: trees, pruning, tree-care, mulberry, bud

I have planted a 15 feet long mulberry plant about a week ago. I don't want it to have any branch in its bottom 7 feet. But I see it is growing new buds everywhere.

When to remove these wanted bottom buds? Right away or let them grow to some length first? Any good way to remove them?

The goal is to let the tree use full power on its top part.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your question, can you add a photo of the plant and tell us where it is?  Why don't you want any branches below 7 feet?

Comment: @kevinskio I have added some pictures. I don't want branches below 7 feet because I want it to occupy the extra area in the bottom part.

Answer (score 1):

I remove unwanted growth when I see it; small enough to be removed with a fingernail is good. However the picture shows a very tall, slim tree which is very prone to wind damage. I would leave lower growth to slow any more top growth this year. It needs at least 3 guy lines at equal spacing ( 120 degrees) for support.

Comment: what are guy lines?

Comment: Rope or wire anchored to the ground and attached to the trunk about the middle of the crown. Attachments need something like a bit of rubber hose on them so they do not damage the bark. They can also be anchored to a house or anything solid where they will not be in the way, much.

Comment: The idea  behind the guy wires is to prevent the tree from moving too much in a high wind; the wires themselves should not be tight against the tree so that it moves a bit in the wind (too tight, and the tree is at risk of developing a weak trunk). My major concern with your tree is the size of the planting hole - is it really only about 30 cms wide and surrounded by an impervious surface? If so, how will the roots be able to keep the tree fed and adequately watered?

Comment: @Jurp Doesn't tree find their moisture once they are established? I have never seen anyone watering trees in the neighborhood. I think there is enough moisture in the groud. Yes, it is about 30cm, I can increase it to 60cm but I think this is enough for now.

Comment: Generally, a tree's root run is the 50% greater than its radius. The small hole isn't really a problem with your young tree, but it will be as the tree grows. If the surface around the hole is NOT impervious, then you're okay with the root run; if it's concrete or something similar, than I'm not sure how the roots will be able to grow well.

Comment: @Jurp it is not concrete. It is a layer of 1-inch thick clay bricks attached with a thin layer of cement. The ground under is mostly sand which whenever I opened was moist because water passes over it for various reasons, like rain, washing.